# Rendering Error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: docpad

I'm getting the following error generated from my default.html.eco layout when I attempt to render:

**RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

My docpad version is: **v6.54.2**, and the specific line causing it is this:

```
<%- @getBlock('scripts').add(['/vendor/foundation.min.js',
'/vendor/audiolib.js','/vendor/freqfinder.js','/vendor/modernizr.js']).toHTML() %>
```

If I remove this, I get a clean build.

Note that the styles block just above it renders just fine:

```
<%- @getBlock("styles").add(['/vendor/foundation.css']).toHTML() %>
```

So I decide to try truncating that list in the scripts block and it works:

```
<%- @getBlock("scripts").add(['/vendor/foundation.min.js']).toHTML() %>
```

Any ideas on how to work around this? I'll go file a bug if I'm not doing something wrong - new to docpad.

Comment: I'd file an issue on github for this one.  I don't see any place where you're fundamentally doing anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is that split into two lines in your actual source code?  Did you try it on a single line?

Comment: Excellent catch: all on a single line appears to work. I'll do a bit more testing, thanks Erv.

Comment: It's not at all obvious to me why it causes that error though.  Probably an oddity of eco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a line break in your code? It fails for me when I copy-paste from here to my layout file, but if I delete the line break between `'/vendor/foundation.min.js',` and `'/vendor/audiolib.js'` then it compiles as expected.

Alternatively, you could also a string of `.add()` commands like this:

```
<%- @getBlock('scripts').add('/vendor/foundation.min.js').add( '/vendor/audiolib.js').add('/vendor/freqfinder.js').add('/vendor/modernizr.js').toHTML() %>
```

That also comiples fine for me.

And a related note, in case anyone else comes across this error but doesn't have any line breaks: `collection.add(null)` now causes the same error message. So, if you're doing something like this:

```
<%- @getBlock("scripts").add( @getDocument().get('scripts') ).toHTML() %>
```

It will die if you don't have a `scripts` metadata field on every page.

The fix, however, is pretty simple:

```
<%- @getBlock("scripts").add( @getDocument().get('scripts') or [] ).toHTML() %>
```